# Is it possible to implement TPH inheritance using [IsNull]/[Is Not Null] condition?

Tags: entity-framework

```
create table Test_Table
(
   ID int primary key identity,
   C1 nvarchar(100) NULL
)
```

`Test_Table` is mapped to `Test_1` entity and is a parent of `Test_2` entity

Is it possible to implement TPH inheritance where depending on whether or not discriminator column `C1` has a null value, a DB record would be materialized either as an entity of type `Test_1` or as an entity of type `Test_2`?

For this to work `Test_1`'s discriminatory column should be set to condition `[C1] Is Not Null` and `Test_2`'s discriminatory column should be set to condition `[C1] is null`. But problem is that condition `Is Not Null` requires us to also map `C1` column to a property, while `Is Null` doesn't allow `C1` to also be mapped to a property.

So is it possible to implement such a condition using only conditional mappings?

Thank you

Comment: Never tried, but I see a problem: what value should EF put in that column when creating a `Test_2`? You can specify a value for the discriminator, but that is used for both read and write. There is no way to specify _different_ read and write conditions.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: " I see a problem: what value should EF put in that column when creating a Test_2?" I don t quite understand your argument, since I don t see why would that be a problem. If the type is Test_2, then EF should assign NULL value for the discriminator property. If we create an entity of type Test_2 and assign non-nullable value to that property, then EF should still be able to save that entity to the DB, even if value is non-nullable?!

Comment: OK, you can configure the discriminator value of the parent class to be `null` and that of the child class to be any other non-null string value, but you should not have `C1` as property in the `Test` classes. It only appears in the mapping configuration (`EntityMappingConfiguration.Requires`).

Answer (score 0):

As titled, this is possible as long as the parent class is associated with the null value, and the child class with a non-null (required) value.

With code-first fluent mappings:

```
public class Test_1
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}

public class Test_2
{
    public string C1 { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbm)
{
    dbm.Entity<Test_1>()
        .Map<Test_2>(m => m.Requires(t => t.C1).HasValue());
}
```

However, it is not possible in the inverse where the parent requires a value, and the child does not.  This is at least in part because it breaks the "is-a" relationship in the inheritance: how can Test_2 *be* a Test_1 if it has a contradictory definition--specifically, that it precludes a value in a field that is required by the parent?